# Sorting a 3 Digit Number vs 4 Digit Number

Tags: swift

I was previously sorting a unique id that consisted of two letters followed by three numbers. This unique id is used to group the entries into a sectioned tableview.

For example [un101, un098, un100, un099, un999] using the below code was working perfectly.

```
self.figuresByLetter = Dictionary(grouping: self.figures, by: { String($0.number[2])}).sorted(by: {$0.0 < $1.0})
```

And resulted in [(key: "0", value: un098, un099), (key: "1", value: un100, un101), (key: "9", value: un999)]

When the number of entries surpassed 1,000, I added a leading zero to the previous entries. I tried updating the code to:

```
self.figuresByLetter = Dictionary(grouping: self.figures, by: { String($0.number[3])}).sorted(by: {$0.0 < $1.0})
```

Now the result is [(key: "0", value: un0098, un0099, un1000, un1001), (key: "1", value: un0100, un0101), (key: "9", value: un0999)]

What can I do so that the entries are in the correct order?

UPDATE:
I figured out an easier way to accomplish exactly what I was looking for.

```
 self.figuresByLetter = Dictionary(grouping: self.figures, by: { String($0.number.prefix(4))}).sorted(by: {$0.0 < $1.0})
```

Comment: `0099` should be less than `1000`. What's the issue? `0` comes before `1`, and `99` is less than `1000`. `ABC0001` comes before `ABC0010`, which goes before `ABC0100`, etc.

Comment: Because currently the numbering goes 0098, 0099, 1000, 1001, 1002, 0100, 0101.

Comment: That shouldn't be possible. You should edit your question to provide the sample entries you're using and the output you're getting (as you just did in your comment), because it's not clear in the problem as you've currently stated it..

Comment: What do you imagine `number[3]` means? Show actual input and actual desired output. Your code is meaningless if we don’t have the input data.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but where are the "two letters"?

Comment: @matt I thought that it meant that the data was sorted based on the digit three spaces from the right. What I don't understand is why it worked perfectly with three digit numbers and no longer does now that I have added the leading zero.

Comment: But _one_ digit alone is not enough to sort a _four_ digit number.

Comment: It's unclear what the dictionary and the grouping are for. Clearly you have some requirement in mind that you have not stated. As long as you just talk about sorting, then saying `sorted` with no closure is quite sufficient. Again I suggest, please show real input and real desired output.

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered (and wouldn't produce the output you're showing, since that's not a dictionary). If you need a specific order, you should use a different type of collection. It would help if you showed how you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

If "the two letters are the same for every entry" and if there are always four digits, then just sort:

```
let input = ["un0098", "un0099", "un1000", "un1001", "un1002", "un0100", "un0101"]
let output = input.sorted()
output // ["un0098", "un0099", "un0100", "un0101", "un1000", "un1001", "un1002"]
```

As you can see, that's the right answer.

Based on that, *now* you can proceed to group into a dictionary and sort by key, like this:

```
let input = ["un0098", "un0099", "un1000", "un1001", "un1002", "un0100", "un0101"]
let output = input.sorted()

let d = Dictionary(grouping: output, by: { s -> String in
    let ix = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy:2)
    let ix2 = s.index(ix, offsetBy:2)
    return String(s[ix..<ix2])
})
let model = d.sorted{$0.key < $1.key}
```

Now `model` is suitable as a datasource for your table view:

```
[(key: "00", value: ["un0098", "un0099"]), 
 (key: "01", value: ["un0100", "un0101"]), 
 (key: "10", value: ["un1000", "un1001", "un1002"])]
```

If that isn't quite what you wanted, it should be easy to see how to tweak it. The *structure* and *order* are correct, so if the data isn't quite the desired format, you can now change it. For example, if you don't like the leading zero in the key names, you can easily get rid of it.

Comment: Yes but this does not achieve the goal of grouping the entries for my sectioned tableview. As I said everything worked perfectly before adding the entries above un1000.

Comment: Yes but there was no grouping or table view in your question statement. That is my point. If you don't say clearly what your input _really_ is and what answer you ultimately _really_ want, it's impossible to help. Keep in mind, too, that dictionaries have _no order_ so there is no such thing as sorting one. Describe the _table_ you are trying to achieve and we can tell you how to construct the _model data_ that will generate it.

Comment: I understand your point. It is difficult to know how much information is needed. I have updated the question. Basically the key determines the section and then all entries that match the key are added to that section. Previously I had sections 0-9 which represented all entries 001-999. Now I am wanting to add section 10 to represent entries 1000-1099.

Comment: Well my answer is still right, because you are proceeding in the wrong order. First sort the array, as I've shown. Now form your groups. Done.